# Extends class from above package

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, project-structure

I have a package with `AbstractTestCase` class that I'd like inherit from in all test classes that are in sub-packages, i.e. `BaseDaoTestRunner`. (See image below)

[image: Project structure]

Problem is that I cannot inherit from that class. I know it's some basic mistake, but I'll appreciate every help provided.

Is it because it's in `test` and not classic `src/main`?

Comment: Show the code so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because it's in test and not classic src/main

No. It's because it's in the default package, and you can't import any class from the default package.

Don't, ever, put anything in the default package. Put all your classes under the standard reverse-dns structure: `com.mycompany.myproject...`

Comment: Still not working. Renamed to `com.company.project` as you said, but still have the problem.

Comment: What is your code? What is the exact and complete error you get from the compiler?

Comment: My bad, sorry. It's working now. As you said, problem was in importing from default package.